Drizzle: generic function that creates select query with pagination & total count
I need to run the same query twice for pagination:

First query: to get the total row count.
Second query: To retrieve data for the current page, which involves ordering the data and applying limit and offset.

The core of the query is identical in both cases, differing only in the fields they select and limit being applied. To avoid repeating the query logic I have created a function to generate it:
function query(fields: any): any {
  return db
    .select(fields)
    .from(hotels)
    .innerJoin(cities, eq(cities.id, hotels.city_id))
    .where(eq(hotels.locale, 'cs'));
}

const total = await query({ count: count() });

const rows = await query({
  id: hotels.id,
  cityId: cities.id,
  name: hotels.name,
})
  .orderBy(hotels.id)
  .limit(limit)
  .offset(offset);

This approach works, but I lose type safety. I haven’t figured out how to properly type the query function. Does anyone have any ideas how to make this work, or how to approach this problem differently?

For pagination:
withPagination<T extends PgSelect>(qb: T, page: number, pageSize: number) {
    return qb.limit(pageSize).offset((page - 1) * pageSize);
}

For count:
async queryWithCount<T extends PgSelect>(qb: T): Promise<[Awaited<T>, number]> {
    const result = await qb;
    // @ts-ignore hack to override internals (not the ideal way)
    qb.config.fields = { count: count() };
    // @ts-ignore
    qb.config.orderBy = [];
    const [total] = await qb;
    return [result, total.count];
}

Finally:
let qb = db
  .select(fields)
  .from(hotels)
  .innerJoin(cities, eq(cities.id, hotels.city_id))
  .where(eq(hotels.locale, 'cs'))
  .orderBy(hotels.id)
  .$dynamic();

qb = withPagination(qb, limit, offset);

const [rows, total] = await queryWithCount(qb);


This does not compile with latest drizzle (0.33.0):
Property 'config' is protected and only accessible within class 'PgSelectQueryBuilderBase<THKT, TTableName, TSelection, TSelectMode, TNullabilityMap, TDynamic, TExcludedMethods, TResult, TSelectedFields>' and its subclasses.
478   qb.config.fields = { count: count() };

@romario333 that's true, I removed ts ignores from the answer, that's the only way I got it to work, please share if you end up finding a better one

I've done this in C# and SQL Server, so I believe the same principles should apply here.
First, just count the rows. You can use whatever method you feel is best, like the count function in database.
Second, get the limited data you want, but set a parameter such that it'll always get the offset. Ex: if input is 1, then first 30 rows. If input is 2, then next 30 rows. I achieved this by creating a SQL procedure.
Third, combine them into a Tuple. I created a C# Tuple<long,List<Object>> and from what I've studied of typescript it sould work the same. The first parameter had the total row count and the second parameter had the row data as a List, which is a typesafe collection of objects.
